# using colClass on quoted csv files with german decimal separator

Tags: r, read.table

I am struggling a little bit with dates and specially german numerics when reading a csv file.

Some examples

```
str(
  read.csv2(text='"Datum";"Betrag";"bla"
"03.05.2018";"-48,50";"skip"
',
sep=';')
)
```

with `read.csv2` it automatically detects the numeric value. But I also want to skip the 3rd column and want to convert the first column into dates.

This is for some reason not working.

```
str(
  read.table(text='"Datum";"Betrag";"bla"
"03.05.2018";"-48,50";"skip"
',
colClasses=c('Date','numeric', "NULL"),
header=TRUE, sep=';', dec=',')
)
```

For some reason, my `colClass` `"numeric"` is not accepted, my date is also not possible to convert. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: dplyr's `read_csv` recognize date classe

Comment: thanks, this helped, but it is `readr::read_csv()` and not `dplyr`.

Comment: That's true! I usually call `readr` by calling `tidyverse` packages. My mistake! Thanx